# How would you set the Article Manager Options in Joomla 3.x programmatically?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am trying to figure out how to set the set the Article Manager Options in Joomla 3.x programmatically or via a file either uploaded to a Joomla folder or preferably via a template. I know there is an option to use a different layout but I am not sure if I can use this to set the other options and if so how? Is this even possible or does it have to be done manually for every site?

To further explain/refine my question if you are logged in to the admin area and goto System > Global Config > Articles you will come to a page like the attached image: [image: Article Manager Options]

There is an option to choose a Layout. My question is where or how would you control the Article Manager Options via the layout, I would like a way to quickly disable most of the options that are on by default.

Comment: @GDP I refined my question, but I left it here to keep from duplicating it.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be best to check at http://joomla.stackexchange.com with your question.  You're a little vague about how/where you want to do this, so I'd suggest starting with [this answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/9030/integrating-extensive-static-html-site-into-a-joomla-website/9439#9439), paying attention to `$article_model = new ContentModelArticle(array('table_path' => $basePath.'/tables'));`.  The options you're interested in are in the column `attribs`, and is stored with the model using an array.